# Вопрос, связанный с СПП.

Tags: синтаксис

"Пока его нет, я обычно убираюсь". Грамматическая основа главной части мне ясна (я убираюсь). Разве тут две грамматические основы? В придаточной части я такую не нахожу...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Придаточная часть представляет собой односоставное безличное предложение, главный член предложения - слово НЕТ. Материал 8 класса. Все впереди!